# Trying to set array variable from part of another array variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a part of array variable into a new array variable like below:

```
$this->data['uploadFront'] = array();
$this->data['uploadFront'] = $this->data['Card']['uploadFront'];
```

But I'm getting undefined index error.

The $this->data['Card'] array is like below:

```
Array
(
    [Card] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [company_name] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [lastname] => 
            [position] => 
            [location] => 
            [phone] => 
            [website] => 
            [mobile] => 
            [comp_name] => 0
            [uploadFront] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

            [uploadBack] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

What could be wrong that needs to be fixed in this process?

Comment: which of the indexes is undefined?

Comment: If you say "The $this->data['Card'] array is like below:" and below, the first key is 'Card' and you are trying to access 'uploadFront' in your line...so practically by what you are saying there you should have: `$this->data['uploadFront'] = $this->data['Card']['Card']['uploadFront'];`

Comment: Tell us, how do you pass the $this->data variable to your method? I mean, what do you ask php? And indeed, if you tell us the $this->data['Card'] array is what you're using, and not the $this->data array, you have no index because you're trying to reach the array you're actually trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->data['uploadFront'][] = $this->data['Card']['uploadFront'];
```

If you want to append to array, you have to use **[]** to show that you are appending, not assinging.

Comment: sorry I've tried that but I'm getting same error. This is used in php class.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't read your post right the first time.

As Catalin told you, if your array is what you tell us, ie $this->data['Card'] = ARRAY, you're creating an unnecessary extra level: two times 'Card', so ['Card']['Card']. I propose you define $this->data as what you told is your array, and then ask to copy ['uploadFront'] to the first level of your $this->data array. In what you described you're trying to access an unexisting part of the array.

In code (probably you'll need to declare the $this->data array somewhere else in your classes, but for the sake of explaining I write it down like this):

```
$this->data = array
(
'Card' => array
    (
        'name' => '',
        'company_name' => '', 
         ...
        'uploadFront' => array
            (
                'name' =>'', 
                'type' => '',
                'tmp_name' => '',
                'error' => '4',
                'size' => '0'
            )

        'uploadBack' => array
            (
               ...
            )

    )

$this->data['uploadFront'] = $this->data['Card']['uploadFront'];
```